# GCC version in binary files

Tags: compiler-construction, binaryfiles

When I cat a binary file like this `cat /bin/cat`, I see that something like this is included in binary almost every time;

```
GCC: (GNU) 4.6.3
```

And some other things like, `.gnu.version.gnu.version_r` or `gnu.build-id.gnu.hash` . Is there any reasons why these things are included in binary files?

Answer (score 0):

For debugging and compatibility purposes.  You can use readelf to see this information in a more readable format (try readelf -V binaryFile).  To get rid of some of the extra information, you can run the strip command.

As always, "man readelf" and "man strip" for more information!